# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el color de fondo de algunas marcas hr usando CSS externo?

Tags: html, css, web, aplicación-web

soy algo nuevo en HTML y en CSS y me tope con el siguiente problema, estoy desarrollando un pequeño sitio de prueba con la finalidad de desarrollar una plataforma de un proyecto que tengo en marcha y en un documento CSS tengo la siguiente configuración:

```
      hr {
    border-style: none;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: white;
 

  .idealeshr {
    border-style: dotted none none none;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    border-color: white;
```

Mi finalidad es que solo los hr en ideales.html tengan la configuración de la clase "idealeshr" y que los hr en otros documentos tengan la configuración de hr y todo "resulta", el problema es que la propiedad del color de fondo blanco también se aplica a la clase "idealeshr" y no quiero que pase eso, esa clase no quiero que tenga color de fondo, el problema lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
  .idealeshr {
border-style: dotted none none none;
border-top-width: 10px;
width: 10%;
border-color: white;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

añadiendo esa propiedad de background a la clase, pero siento que hay mejores formas de solucionar mi problema para evitar añadir una linea de mas, espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar eso y si tienen alguna recomendación para mejorar mi "codigo" será también bienvenida.

En respuesta a otro usuario, adjunto la estructura de los archivos descritos en el problema:

Los hr de aquí, deben tener solo el formato de hr en el CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>¿Qué Trama La Urdimbre?</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="index.html" target="_self">Inicio</a></td>
      <td><a href="organigrama.html" target="_self">Organigrama</a></td>
      <td><a href="ideales.html" target="_self">Ideales</a></td>
      <td><a href="contacto.html" target="_self">Contacto</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <h1>¿Qué Trama La Urdimbre?</h1>
  <img src="src\img\circle-cropped.png" alt="Foto de perfil de Rodrigo" width="500">
  <h2>Objetivos de la plataforma:</h2>
  <p><em>Por: Rodrigo Delgadillo</em></p>
  <ul>
    <li>Permitir el libre acceso a la informacion.</li>
    <li>Redactar y publicar articulos de interes y de consulta textil.</li>
    <li>Crear articulos con informacion confiable, con fuentes bibliograficas correctamente citadas y <br>
      con la aprobacion de un profesional en el area</li>
    <li>Ademas de articulos, crear videos, podcasts e inforgafias con los mismos principios a fin de abarcar mas usuarios</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <h2>Redes Sociales</h2>
  <strong><a href="https://www.facebook.com/quetramalaurdimbre" target="_blank">Facebook</a></strong><br>
  <br>
  <hr>
</body>

</html>
```

Y los de aquí el formato de .idealeshr y solo eso, no tomar el color de fondo blanco para los demás hr.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ideales del Proyecto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="index.html" target="_self">Inicio</a></td>
        <td><a href="organigrama.html" target="_self">Organigrama</a></td>
        <td><a href="ideales.html" target="_self">Ideales</a></td>
        <td><a href="contacto.html" target="_self">Contacto</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>Ideales Generales</h1>
      <p><em>Por: Nach Campa</em></p>
    <h2>Mision</h2>
    <p>Nuestra misión es darle voz al mundo textil considerando los diferentes contextos que existen en él hoy en día, desde el sector Artesanal,<br>
      Industrial, Alta Costura, Innovación, Tecnología, Emprendimiento. Creando contenido de interés YouTube, común y profesional, a través<br>
      de distintos medios como lo es un Podcast disponible en diferentes plataformas, contenido de publicación de artículos de consulta, entre otros. </p><br>
      <hr class="idealeshr">
    <h2>Vision</h2>
    <p>Ser el principal medio de divulgación textil para cualquier interesado en las distintas áreas y disciplinas inmersas en el sector textil.</p><br>
    <hr class="idealeshr">
    <h2>Objetivos</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>Nuestro <strong>objetivo a corto plazo</strong> es crear nuevo contenido en el podcast, y en YouTube, haciendo reportajes de ferias nacionales importantes,<br>
          escuelas e industrias relacionadas con el mundo de los textiles, además de la publicación de artículos de consulta e interés con temáticas de<br>
          cada área del mundo textil.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Nuestro <strong>objetivo a mediano plazo</strong> es crear una plataforma, para la publicación y consulta de artículos científicos y libros con temática de<br>
          textiles, además de crear cursos que serán herramientas de trabajo para personas que trabajan en el sector textil. Abarcando desde la hilatura,<br>
          tejido, acabado, confección, control de calidad entre otros.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Nuestro objetivo a largo plazo es ser reconocidos en el sector, colaborar con diferentes empresas del sector textil, proponer nuevas formas de<br>
          trabajo implementando técnicas sustentables, además de promover y reconocer las acciones de empresas que están desarrollando estas técnicas<br>
          para lograr el equilibrio sustentable. Y proponerlo como forma de producción más eficiente seguir con difusión de información y crear una red <br>
          en comunidad para promover el trabajo mexicano como una forma de retroalimentación cultural. </p>
      </li><br>
    </ul>
    <hr class="idealeshr">
    <h2>Politicas</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Fomentar valores dentro de nuestro equipo de trabajo para el mejoramiento de las relaciones de trabajo.</li>
      <li>
        <p>Estamos al servicio de la comunidad textil, comprometidos con darle la voz que merece y fomentar nuevas metodologías de organización para <br>
          diferentes contextos.</p>
      </li>
      <li>Elaborar material confiable y de calidad atreves de métodos eficaces.</li><br>
      <li>Crear tema de debate y difusión de información en pro del desarrollo textil.</li>
      <li>
        <p>Mejorar el contenido cada vez más, teniendo en cuenta los temas propuestos por la audiencia con la finalidad de crear contenido que mejore sus<br>
          expectativas.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>La idea de crear la comunidad de textileros es darle voz a las mejoras que deben existir dentro y fuera de la industria, con la finalidad de empezar<br>
          a entregar y exigir productos de calidad con la finalidad de hacer mejoras constantes dentro de nuestros sistemas de producción en el país.</p>
      </li><br>
    </ol>
    <hr class="idealeshr">
    <h2>Valores</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Ética</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Respeto</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Familia</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Integridad</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Amor</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Lealtad</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Paz</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Responsabilidad</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Crecimiento</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Eficiencia</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Creatividad</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Innovacion</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Propocision</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Calidad</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Patriotismo</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Perseverancia</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Benevolecia</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Tolerancia</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Trabajo en equipo</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Adaptacion a los cambios</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Analisis de la situacion actual</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

El CSS es el siguiente:

```
  body {
    background-color: #79e4f2;
  }

  hr {
    border-style: none;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .idealeshr {
    border-style: dotted none none none;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h2 {
    color: white;
  }
```

Como pueden observar, solucione el problema añadiendo lo siguiente:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

a .idealeshr, pero quiero saber si hay una mejor forma de hacer lo que digo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de utilizar `background-color: white;` para el `hr` podrías utilizar border tal como lo haces para `.idealeshr.

Puedes simplificar toadvía más el código si declaras primero `border:none;` sobreescribiendo el valor del `border-top`. Por favor observa que para `.idealeshr` ya no necesitas `border:none;` ya que lo hereda de `hr`

```css
body {
  background-color: #79e4f2;
}

hr {
  border:none;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  width: 20%;
}

.idealeshr {
  border-top: 10px dotted white;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<hr class="idealeshr">
<hr>
<hr class="idealeshr">
<hr>
<hr class="idealeshr">
<hr>
<hr class="idealeshr">
```

Comment: Vaya... esto era justo lo que buscaba y no me había dado cuenta de eso... que en .idealeshr ya no era necesario el border: none; muchas gracias de verdad, enseguida aplicare la corrección.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor para solucionar es esto es utilizar Pseudo Selectores CSS; [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) te dejo una lista

Si solo quieres marcar un elemento puede utilizar el Pseudo selector **`:first-child`** u otros. También te sugiero que pongas el código completo para que podamos entender mejor el problema.

PD: Recuerda siempre cerrar las llaves en CSS :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, tome en cuenta tus comentarios y añadí el resto del código, espero me puedas ayudar mejor de esa forma. PD Las llaves de cierre si las tenia, pero por algún motivo aquí quedaron fuera del código y las quite. 